# jQuery - A "slider" or "carousel" in the list links but

Tags: jquery, list, hyperlink, slider, carousel

Providing fiddle of the function: https://jsfiddle.net/qpguk0xf/

From the list of links class "Others":

```
<div class="others">
<ul>
<li class="active"><a href="path-to-article" data-article="art-1">Article 1</a></li>
<li><a href="path-to-article" data-article="art-2">Article 2</a></li>
<li><a href="path-to-article" data-article="art-3">Article 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I made a script that when you click it will show the respective article (that has an ID equal to the data-article attribute) and hide the other, after that I made a interval for it to trigger the click event on each of that links in a time, the entire function is:

```
$(function() {
  $('.others a[data-article]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $article = $(this).data('article'),
        $carouselIT = $('#' + $article);

            $('.others').find('li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');

                $('.carouselbg').each(function() {
                    $(this).fadeOut('fast'); 
                });

                $carouselIT.fadeIn('slow');
        });

        var elements = $('.others').find('a[data-article]');
        var index = 1;

        elements.eq(0).trigger('click'); // just to show the first item

        var interval = setInterval(clickTo, 6000);

        function clickTo() {
           elements.eq(index).trigger("click");
           index++;
           if(index == elements.size()){
           index = 0;
           }
        };

        $('#carousel').hover(function(ev){
           clearTimeout(interval);
        }, function(ev){
           interval = setInterval(clickTo, 6000);
        });

});
```

I know that the code is really messed up but it does work. But, what my problem is?
When the user actually click on an link of the list it shows exactly how it needs to, but when the user leaves the area of the slider and the timer start again (when hover it, the time stops and then start over) the "index" of the interval start where it stops, in other words:
If the function index is in "2" and the user click on the "link 1" when the timer start over it will not continue from where the user click, it will continue where it stops, so it won't go to "2" as it should, but to "3".

Is there a way to everytime the user click in a link the "index" start counting from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initially set `index` to `0` and call `clickTo()` to display the first article. Then when an article is clicked, you can use the [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) method to get the index of the clicked link within the set of links.

Here is what I think you can have:

```
$(function () {
    var $links = $('.others a[data-article]');
    var index = 0;

    $links.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $link = $(this);
            $article = $link.data('article'),
            $carouselIT = $('#' + $article);

        $('.others').find('li').removeClass('active');
        $link.parent('li').addClass('active');

        $('.carouselbg').fadeOut('fast');

        $carouselIT.fadeIn('slow');

        index = ($links.index($link) + 1) % $links.length;
    });

    clickTo(); // just to show the first item

    var interval = setInterval(clickTo, 6000);

    function clickTo() {
        $links.eq(index).trigger("click");
    };

    $('#carousel').hover(function (ev) {
        clearTimeout(interval);
    }, function (ev) {
        interval = setInterval(clickTo, 6000);
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uhkpfxbj/2/)

Notice I changed `elements.size()` to `$links.length` since the [`.size()`](https://api.jquery.com/size/) method was deprecated. I also removed the use of `.each()` to fade out the articles because it was unnecessary.

Comment: Works like a charm! And the function is so smaller and works flawless, thanks mate! I really appreciate this! And thanks to teach me that I was using unnecessary methods, omg you're amazing! haha